# React.js vs Auto-Layout

Tags: ios8, autolayout, reactjs

We are thinking about moving from Auto-Layout to React.js.

How does React.js build for multiple screen sizes: 3.5", 4.7", 5.5", iPad Mini, iPad Air ?  and why is it easier in React.js ?

Has anyone made the transition?  Please share your experience?

Comment: Why do you want to switch from Auto-Layout to React.js? Did you have problems with the current approach? If yes, please ask them here as it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: And are you referring to xcode's auto layout feature, or to a javascript framework?

Comment: How is it not clear what I'm asking?

Comment: Please see my second question: are you referring to xcode's auto layout feature, or to a javascript framework?

Comment: I'm asking the how does React.js design for multiple screens.  And if someone has had experience, is it easier to maintain/developer for react vs auto-layout?

Comment: So do you currently have a native app and want to switch to a phonegap/cordova one?

Comment: I do have a native app, but I want to switch to React.js for UI.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a discussion and opinion board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `React.js` framework is to help you create reusable components for your application. It doesn't enforce any structure of the `html` content, and it doesn't natively have support for things like auto-layout, since that's the role of `CSS`.

There is no direct `auto-layout` support in `react`, and there's no UI editor like `interface builder` where you can set the constraints for a particular `html element`. You can achieve similar results, but you'll need to write CSS rules for that.